# Sort a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

This is how my list look after using some csv parsing:

```
list=[['1131', '01/06/15', 'PROFI ROM FOOD SRL', '290.7'],
         ['1131', '', '', ''], ['2024194PJ', '01/08/15', 
        'SOCIETATEA NATIONALA DE', '2,088.17'], ['2024194PJ', '', 'RADIOCOMUNICATII SA', '']]
```

(this is a data sample, actual list will be bigger)
I will parse that list:

```
for a in list:
   for x in a:
      if ....:
         anotherlist.append(x)
```

I want this output:

```
anotherlist=[['1131', '01/06/15', 'PROFI ROM FOOD SRL', '290.7'],
['2024194PJ', '01/08/15', 'SOCIETATEA NATIONALA DE RADIOCOMUNICATII
SA', '2,088.17']]
```

I want append the 2rd index value to each previous list and delete that  specific list, so this

```
[['2024194PJ', '01/08/15', 'SOCIETATEA NATIONALA DE', 
 '2,088.17'], ['2024194PJ', '', 'RADIOCOMUNICATII SA', '']]
```

will be this

```
[['2024194PJ', '01/08/15', 
'SOCIETATEA NATIONALA DE RADIOCOMUNICATII SA', '2,088.17']]
```

and also get rid of this format

```
['1131', '', '', '']
```

But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the list will always follow the schema you provided:

```
list2 = []
for i in range(len(list)/2):
    list2 += [[list[i*2][0],
               list[i*2][1],
               list[i*2][2] + ' ' + list[i*2+1][2],
               list[i*2][3]]]
```

**Explanation:**
We start with an empty list (list2):

```
list2 = []
```

A for loop then goes through the whole of your list, but only looks at every second element:

```
for i in range(len(list)/2):
```

At each step, it adds a new entry to list2:

```
list2 +=
```

This new entry is a combination of two list elements, list[i*2] and list[i*2+1]:

```
         [[list[i*2][0],
           list[i*2][1],
           list[i*2][2] + ' ' + list[i*2+1][2],
           list[i*2][3]]]
```

Comment: Perfect, that works, can you explain me what you did there? Thanks alot!

Comment: @Rommel I added some details to the answer.

Comment: I got that points, but how is the loop ignoring the lists that I dont need? Thanks!

Comment: Those lists are not ignored, but because their third elements are empty strings (''), adding them doesn't change anything. Example: 'apple' + ' pie' = 'apple pie', 'apple' + '' = 'apple'